# What libraries will parse a DTD using PHP

Tags: php, parsing, dtd

I need to parse DTDs using PHP and am hoping there's a *simple* library to help out. Each DTD has numerous `<!ENTITY...` and `<!-- Comment...` elements, which I need to act upon.

Note that I do *not* need to validate anything against these DTDs, simply parse them as data files themselves.

A few options I've looked at:

[James Clarke's SD](http://jclark.com/sp/), which is an option of last resort, but I'd like to avoid the complexity of building/installing/configuring code external to PHP. I'm not sure it's even possible in my situation.

PEAR has an [XML_DTD_Parser](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_DTD/docs/latest/XML_DTD/XML_DTD_Parser.html), which requires installing/configuring PEAR and a number of pear modules, which I'm also not sure is possible, and would rather avoid. Has anyone used it with success? **EDIT:** I've since learned that XML_DTD_Parser discards comments, so is not a valid option for my needs.

[PHP XML Classes](http://phpxmlclasses.sourceforge.net/) has the class_path_parser, which another site suggested, but it fails to read ENTITY elements. It appears to be using PHP's built in XML parsing capabilities, which use EXPAT.

PHP's [DOMDocument will validate against a DTD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.validate.php), so must be able to read them, though I don't see how to get at the DTD parser directly at first glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the standard XML parsers for PHP give access to *general* entities*, and few give access to comments. PHP's built in [XML Parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) uses [Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/), but does not expose the full expat API; in particular, a handler for entities cannot be set. There is a [PHP bug](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51939) filed to add this.

AFAICT, the only way to handle comments and general entities in a DTD parser is to write your own parser; either by hand, or using one of the lexers and parser generators available for php (e.g. [PHP_LexerGenerator](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_LexerGenerator) and [PHP_ParserGenerator](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_ParserGenerator) among others).

* PHP's expat wrapper (XML Parser) does give access to notation declarations, which are similar to, but not the same as general entities.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know useful this will be...

If I understand what you're looking for, you're looking for a means to extract the  and  "nodes" from a DTD in order to act on them. Very interesting. Here's where my brain went:

- Use [DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) directly. Looks as if there's no distinct way of getting at the DTD data if you treat the DTD as the source.
- Use the [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) in the same way. Ditto.
- Use the [XML parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) in, again, the same way but use some of the entity declaration handler functions to get information out. I think this proves more foresight and is probably not what you need. (Although I could be wrong.)
- Use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), or the like, to grab your values based on the patterns. Not to dissimilar to [other thoughts in the world](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/9368.htm).
- Use XSLT to nix everything but what you need. The .xsl to remove all non-comments would be pretty easy to manage. It's quite possible you could just [output them in a format that's easier to parse](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/09/13/xslt/index.html) (say, in a better XML structure). Entities may require handling via PHP's [XSL processor](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php). I'm a little rusty on entities.

Regardless, I hope some of this helps.