# Can I echo all HTML tags in the W3C specification using DOM?

Tags: php, dom

I'm using this simple PHP HTML parser: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net. Is it possible to use it to echo all tags of the HTML specification?

Comment: Do you mean echo all the tags that exist in your current HTML document, or all the HTML tags that exist in the HTML specification?

Comment: all the tags exist in the html specification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-transitional.xsd');
$xsns = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema';
$elements = array();
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagNameNS($xsns, 'element') as $element) {
    if ($element->hasAttribute('name')) {
        echo $element->getAttribute('name');
        $docs = $element->getElementsByTagNameNS($xsns, 'documentation');
        foreach ($docs as $doc) {
            echo "\t", $doc->nodeValue;
        }
        echo PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

The above code will output all the Element types in the Schema definition (not DTD) for [XHTML1 Transitional](http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-transitional.xsd) (not HTML) plus any documentation, e.g.

```
pre
      content is "Inline" excluding
         "img|object|applet|big|small|sub|sup|font|basefont"
```

It uses PHP's native DOM extension to do that. [The DOM extension](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) uses [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/) underneath and is superior to SimpleHtmlDom in terms of speed and offered control over the markup. [The DOM interface is a language agnostic W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/).

For alternatives to the DOM extension see

- [Best methods to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662) (most of these apply to XML too)

Comment: For comparing Simple Html DOM Parser against DOMDocument, see my answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098895/how-to-determine-if-text-string-appears-as-a-child-of-a-named-html-tag/4235909#4235909), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735291/domdocument-class-unable-access-domnode/4230447#4230447) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044812/regex-domdocument-match-and-replace-text-not-in-a-link/4209925#4209925).

Answer (score 1):

No, that parser is a simple HTML parser, it has no capability to parse a DTD and it's internal logic for handling HTML elements is no exposed (or even expressed in a way that would making presenting it in human readable form even slightly convenient).

Comment: what should i do to echo an html tags?

Comment: That's a different question, and people would need to know why you are trying to do that in order to provide a good answer.

Comment: I found a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917940/what-libraries-will-parse-a-dtd-using-php if there is a dtd parser, but unfortunately, none exist.

Comment: @Stupefy not true. The question names the [PEAR package XML_DTD_Parser](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_DTD/docs/latest/XML_DTD/XML_DTD_Parser.html)

Answer (score -2):

In the documentation it says

```
// Dumps the internal DOM tree back into string
$str = $html;

// Print it!
echo $html;
```

I think the echo should be $str not $html but this is what the documentation says.

---

```
// Dumps the internal DOM tree back into string
$str = $html->save();

// Dumps the internal DOM tree back into a file
$html->save('result.htm');
```

Hope this helps.

Documentation: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm